# Is there a way to reset multiple values to empty strings from input elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to add four new pieces of information **(name, address, phone number, and email)** to the table. There is an event handler `handleAddFormChange` for storing that information, and a submit handler `handleAddFormSubmit` to update the state with the latest information. I would like to reset all four input elements to empty strings once I clicked the add button to trigger the submit handler.

I've come across some solutions on the internet and my current solution is to set all input to empty strings by using

```
e.target[0].value = "";
e.target[1].value = "";
e.target[2].value = "";
e.target[3].value = "";
```

on `handleAddFormSubmit`. Is there a more elegant way to reset all those inputs?

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import ReadOnlyRow from "./components/readOnlyRow";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      fullName: "Jenny Chan",
      address: "3 waterfoot road",
      phoneNumber: "333-962-7516",
      email: "jenny.chan@email.com",
    },
  ]);

  const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const handleAddFormChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fieldName = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    let fieldValue = e.target.value;
    let newDataForm = { ...addFormData };
    newDataForm[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    setAddFormData(newDataForm);
    console.log(e);
  };

  const handleAddFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newContact = {
      id: nanoid(),
      fullName: addFormData.fullName,
      address: addFormData.address,
      phoneNumber: addFormData.phoneNumber,
      email: addFormData.email,
    };
    let newContacts = [...contacts, newContact];
    setContacts(newContacts);
  
    // current solution to reset inputs
    e.target[0].value = "";
    e.target[1].value = "";
    e.target[2].value = "";
    e.target[3].value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <form>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {contacts.map((contact) => (
              <Fragment>
                <ReadOnlyRow contact={contact} />
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

      <h2>Add a contact</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fullName"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a name"
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter an address"
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="phoneNumber"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a phone number"
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          required="email"
          placeholder="Enter an email"
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import ReadOnlyRow from "./components/readOnlyRow";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

const formInitialValue = {
    fullName: "",
    address: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
  }

function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      fullName: "Jenny Chan",
      address: "3 waterfoot road",
      phoneNumber: "333-962-7516",
      email: "jenny.chan@email.com",
    },
  ]);

  const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState(formInitialValue);

  const handleAddFormChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fieldName = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    let fieldValue = e.target.value;
    let newDataForm = { ...addFormData };
    newDataForm[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    setAddFormData(newDataForm);
    console.log(e);
  };

  const handleAddFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newContact = {
      id: nanoid(),
      fullName: addFormData.fullName,
      address: addFormData.address,
      phoneNumber: addFormData.phoneNumber,
      email: addFormData.email,
    };
    let newContacts = [...contacts, newContact];
    setContacts(newContacts);
  
    // current solution to reset inputs
   setAddFormData(formInitialValue)
  };

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <form>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {contacts.map((contact) => (
              <Fragment>
                <ReadOnlyRow contact={contact} />
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

      <h2>Add a contact</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fullName"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a name"
          value={addFormData.fullName}
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter an address"
          value={addFormData.address}
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="phoneNumber"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Enter a phone number"
          value={addFormData.phoneNumber}
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          required="email"
          placeholder="Enter an email"
          value={addFormData.email}
          onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        ></input>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```